# How to parse a string in python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to parse a string. Like if this is the string `"(A (B (C D) (E F)) (G H))`", then I want to parse it like A has children B and G, B has children C and E, and no one else has any children. So, I want the output to be `['A_B_G', 'B_C_E']`

I'm doing something like:

```
lst=[]
str = (A (B (C D) (E F)) (G H))
lst.append(str.split(' '))
```

And then I'm stuck!

Could somebody give me an idea what to do next?

Comment: Recursion is a useful way to approach problems like this.

Comment: As a fist step, try spitting up the string by seniority

Comment: [This article](http://probablyprogramming.com/2009/11/23/a-simple-lisp-parser-in-python) solves a similar problem with the use of a stack.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather not hint too much, but you can start by converting the list into one like

```
['(', 'A', '(', 'B', ...]
```

and then you go over it taking different actions depending on the type of symbol you see e.g. `(`, `)` or a letter.

Comment: I did that. Then what actions should I take and how? Coz I need to find the corresponding closing parentheses for an opening parentheses, how do I do that?